# Does scipy.optimize has a limit in equation?

Tags: pandas, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am doing a curve fit with scipy optimize. I did it a few times before and I got good results. But now I do a curve fit with around 1.000.000 rows in my df. I don't get an Error but my maximum in the curve fit is around 100 larger then my highest Y value from my df.

Does someone has an idea why the curve is so much higher than the actual Y values? My idea is that Scipy can only use the first ... rows from my df?

I am using this formula:

```
def logifunc(x,c,a,b):   
    return c / (1 + (a) * np.exp(-b*(x)))
```

This is the result (The light green is the curve fit and the dark green is the Y-value average for each X-value):

[image]

Comment: I'd be very surprised if `scipy` would silently ignore parts of the input data. Can it be that the light-green line just is the best possible fit, provided your dark-green data? What happens if you cut off the part with `x>20`, where the data obviously does not match your applied model? I suspect that `scipy` chose this result because it provides the least (mean squared) error, which is dominated by the outliers at `x>20`.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I don't think that that the curve fit is the best possible fit. I did it many times before. Always with the same formula and the same code. My previous results are so much better than this one. I also tried it with `x<20` but it doesn't change. I filtered all my df for realistic values ( I never had to do it before it just worked fine and compensated it).

Comment: That's strange. Did you try to reduce the size, e.g. using every second value (`values[::2]`)? If there is a size limit, you should get better results with a smaller size, and if you have lots of values, then downsampling it should not effect the fit much.

Comment: I tried to do it with less values. Still no difference. I think this is just the result from the curve. I don't get why... Which value makes the curve grow so high when I don't have any value higher than 1850. My curve reaches 1950 at the highest point.

Comment: Can you (e.g. manually) find a set of parameters that appears to fit your data better? If not, then your data might not follow `logifunc` as well as you thought. If you find such parameters, you can compute the mean squared error for the new and the old parameters to (hopefully) confirm that `curve_fit` found the solution with minimum MSE.

Comment: Hey, just for your interest. I filtered my data and left out the x values in the middle. In that case it works on the maximum. So the problem is that the curve bends to much at x= 10-13. 
Thank you for your help!